# Android Client side performance testing

Tags: android, performance

Is there a program or SDK that can help with Android client side performance testing which is basically seeing how long visual changes to the user take in time. This is like instruments for IOS but for Android. I'm slightly confused because I already know of MAT, view hierarchy, PMD, StrictMode, DEBUG (cpu profiler), and Lint. However I'm being told that we need some automated tool for checking how long it would take visually for a person to click a button and then go to the next page. Is this even possible?